# View Additional image on JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

I create a login box with JFrame that do not let user to enter empty Or have letter username and password.

My login frame and main frame class, both are jframe(extends jframe) and i want to use this ImagePanel class for both of them.
But, i want to change its painComponents() method for my each class.

Can I change ImagePanel class abstract to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) .Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example.

Comment: I"m not sure why your code is not working well, but one thing that bugs me (but is probably not causing your problem), is that you appear to be trying to set the look and feel *after* creating your GUI components, and I believe that this can cause problems. This should only be done *before* creating your Swing GUI components. And you in fact seem to do this as well, that you seem to be trying to set the look and feel ***twice***?

Comment: I delete the setlookandfeel method in my IDE, But not solved!

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is with your ImagePanel. Maybe you need a super.paintComponent() when you override the paintComponent() method to paint the image.

Comment: @camickr This should be an answer

Comment: I add super.painComponent method and it works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call the `repaint()` method.

Also, if adding new components you must validate the frame as well:

```
validate();
repaint();
```

Comment: Where exactly call this methods?

Comment: After you change the frame.

Comment: The problem is the OP isn't calling super.paintXxx on there ImagePanel.  Because the background isn't been cleared on each paint cycle, anything previously painting isn't been cleared from the graphics context